# How Datapump is faster than export/import backup?

Tags: oracle, export, backup, datapump

Why is datapump export faster than `exp`?

Answer (score 3):

Datapump is much more efficient than `exp`:

Datapump runs within the Oracle server processes, and can read directly from the database files and write directly to a file on the server. As I understand it, data access is direct, not via SQL.

`exp` uses the ordinary Oracle Call Interface (OCI) -- the library that Oracle provides to connect to the database. It can only run ordinary SQL statements like any other program.

Answer (score 0):

Also data pump can run in parallel, and has the option to append data, truncate tables or replace table. In addition you can change table spaces when you import. It is a better utility in every way than the older exp/imp tool.